# mongodb c# addShardTag

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a way to add a Shard Tag (as found in [addShardTag](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.addShardTag/) ) for shell access) via c#?

I have a server program which creates collections dynamically. Each collection has thousands of records from IOT devices and I would like to keep collections to different shards using shard tags.

As the collections are created dynamically, I cannot go to mongo shell every time to attach the shard tag. Can some one point to the code snippet of how to achieve this via CommandDocument and mongoAdminDb.RunCommand ?
I have searched